# copying a directory files into current directory

Tags: bash, unix

If I have a directory "test" and inside a directory "new" and I want to copy all files from "new" to test(my current directory).
I tried: cp -r new . because I know dot is like current directory but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are in "test":

`cp -r new/* .`

To test:

```
mkdir test                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
cd test                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
mkdir new                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
touch new/1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
touch new/2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
touch new/3 
cp -r new/* .
```

Output:

```
$ ls 
1  2  3  new
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
     cp -rf present/directory /desire/directory
```